# Sql Pivot returning 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a sql query that is meant to count accounts that belong to a certain group. I am using a pivot for that. While the result set looks right, it returns all 0 counts

my tsql code:

```
  select
    *
from
(
    select 
        id,
        accountnumber,
        group
    from dbo.dataTable
)data
pivot
(
    count(accountnumber),
    for group IN (['@SGMLS L1'],['@SGMLS L2'],['@SGMLS L3'],['@SGMLS L4'],['@SGMLS L5'])
)
```

This is what the result Set Looks Like:

```
id      '@SGMLS L1' '@SGMLS L2'     '@SGMLS L3'     '@SGMLS L4'     '@SGMLS L5'
0100            0       0               0               0               0
0200            0       0               0               0               0
0300            0       0               0               0               0
0400            0       0               0               0               0
0600            0       0               0               0               0
0800            0       0               0               0               0
1100            0       0               0               0               0
1200            0       0               0               0               0
1400            0       0               0               0               0
1500            0       0               0               0               0
1600            0       0               0               0               0
```

Sample data

```
id   accountnumber group 
---- ----------- ------------
0100 75          "@SGMLS L1 " 
0200 109         "@SGMLS L1 " 
0200 117         "@SGMLS L4 " 
0200 125         "@SGMLS L4 " 
0600 158         "@SGMLS L4 " 
0200 166         "@SGMLS L1 " 
0600 174         "@SGMLS L4 " 
1200 364         "@SGMLS L3 " 
1200 398         "@SGMLS L2 "
```

Please Help.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Quick guess: use `SUM(1)` instead of `count(accountnumber)`

Comment: Try removing 'id,' from the inner query

Comment: Removing 'id' from the inner query produces same results, only in one row. sum(1) produces an error 'incorrect syntax'.   sample data from inner query:id    accountnumber   group
0100            75    "@SGMLS L1      "
0200            109    "@SGMLS L1      "
0200            117    "@SGMLS L4      "
0200            125    "@SGMLS L4      "
0600            158    "@SGMLS L4      "
0200            166    "@SGMLS L1      "
0600            174    "@SGMLS L4      "
1200            364    "@SGMLS L3      "
1200            398    "@SGMLS L2      "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove `quotes` from pivot `column list`.

```
select
    *
from
(
    select 
        id,
        accountnumber,
        group
    from dbo.dataTable
)data
pivot
(
    count(accountnumber),
    for group IN ([@SGMLS L1],[@SGMLS L2],[@SGMLS L3],[@SGMLS L4],[@SGMLS L5])
)piv
```

By looking at your comments it looks like your `group` column data contains `double quotes` and there is one `space` before the trailing `double quote` if yes then try this.

```
......
......
pivot
(
    count(accountnumber),
    for group IN (["@SGMLS L1 "],["@SGMLS L2 "],["@SGMLS L3 "],["@SGMLS L4 "],["@SGMLS L5 "])
)piv
```